# Color Management in Blender

Tags: 3d-view, color-management, color

Till now I rendered my images and took them to Photoshop and did some color corrections there. Made aware of Color Management options in Blender by Rick's answer on [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49307/color-correction-of-a-video) I am now diving somewhat deeper in Color Management in Blender.

I don't want this post to be a dupe, I just want some basic understanding of color management in Blender. How monitor profiles, color spaces and Blender act together. Like I have some basic understanding how working spaces, monitor profiles act together in Photoshop.

Comment: @poor I have seen that post but that is about monitor calibration and I have a calibrated monitor. Is my question really a dupe ? Hmmm .. perhaps you are right. I did not read the part about hooking the 3D LUT into Blender. Pfff .... heavy stuff

Comment: Ok, retracted. But it should answer [question 3 and 4](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31068/how-can-blender-be-augmented-to-display-color-critical-and-accurate-results/31082#31082). Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @JanScherders http://displaycal.net/ is certainly not the only option, some other companies will be happy to take your money for what you can do accurately for free using open source.

Comment: @JanScherders please read: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1-6sF9XjjZclJ43NDi4fAelVybeCZpp7mOiA2wpxlitA/edit#slide=id.g11f6dea3e1_0_0

Comment: @cegaton Thanks for the link. After a first read I feel very confused. I have a photography background and I am used to live in the world of monitor profiles, AdobeRGB, Pro Photo.

Comment: @JanScherders also read this post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46940/1853 at the end of it there are some links that might interest you.

Comment: @JanScherders I would _strongly_ encourage you to try and get a strong grasp on colour management across domains before delving in deep. I am happy to answer questions to the best of my ability, but many issues with colour arise when a software-centric approach is applied thinking it is a singular end-path. Having a firm grasp on the nuts-and-bolts will make it much easier to understand what is going on under the hood, and help avoid critical errors in workflow.

Comment: @troy_s I agree. I think I had a reasonable understanding of the colour management world of a photographer but I feel now confronted with whole new concepts. Where to begin ?

Comment: @JanScherders You already have. Don't get buried. Try to start with that slide presentation cegaton linked to, and perhaps read the PDF at the VES link http://cinematiccolor.com. Ask questions from there, once you grab onto some of the newer concepts.

Comment: @troy_s I will do that. For now ... would It make sense to use a dedicated monitor for motion and configure that in sRGB ?

Comment: Read through and you will likely have a much better grasp as to how the pieces fit. The short answer is that you can configure things however your pipeline desires. Where you see sRGB is a limitation is purely a small gap in understanding of pipelines and process.