# Is there a way to map a floating point value using a Bezier curve with nodes (Blender 2.8)?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I want to a floating point value in the range [0.0, 1.0] to another floating point value in the same range. I'd like to implement this mapping using a Bezier curve.

I've read the documentation for the RGB Curve node, and also the following  answer ([how does the RGB curve work?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42649/how-does-the-rgb-curve-work)), but I would like to know if there is a way to apply a bezier curve but only to a floating point value (and not to a whole vector).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A potential solution is to use the `RGB Curve` node, but focusing only on one of its channels. In the example below, I am passing as input a floating point value in the range [0.0, 1.0], and the node tree below does the following

1. Feed the input floating point value to the `RGB Curve` node (since the input is one-dimensional, we focus on only one of the RGB channels; red in this example)
2. Separate the output into the three color channels (RGB)
3. Isolate the red channel (at this point the output is still in the same range, [0, 1])
4. Multiply the red channel output by a (problem specific) scaling factor

[image]